# Using Microsoft Access, VBA and SQL what is the simplest way to trim all fields in a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm looking for the simplest way to trim all text/memo fields in an Access table. I'm currently using...

```
    Public Sub Trimmer()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblName")
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.Name
    If fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo Then
    Debug.Print "Since " & fld.Name & " is a text or Memo field we should trim it."
        CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE tblName SET tblName.[" & fld.Name & "] = Trim([" & fld.Name & "]);")
    End If
    Next
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    end sub
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You could trim only the fields/records needed:

```
CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE tblName SET [" & fld.Name & "] = LTrim([" & fld.Name & "]) Where Left([" & fld.Name & "], 1) = ' ';")
```